# Power analysis for binomial data when sample sizes are different

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

I'm running an A/B test where I want to compare two different layout of a button and want to see if one layout lead to a higher Click-Through Rate with a certain statistical power. I want to use a significance level of 0.05.

Layout 1 has 25302 visualization and received 40 clicks.
Layout 2 has 27924 visualization and received 50 clicks.

The distribution is binomial, considering the nature of the event I'm studying. Every visualization can in fact lead to a click or not.

I was trying to calculate it in R, using the `pwr.2p2n.test()` function included in the `pwr` library. The downside of this function is that it's asking the effect size as an input, which I don't know how to calculate.

Comment: Yes and no, I would like to know in the first place if the the pwr.2p2n.test() function the right solution. If that's the case I would like to know how to calculate the effect size parameter.

Comment: Power is not that relevant after the data are collected.  I would stick to a confidence interval for the difference in two probabilities.

Comment: The test is still running. I don't plan to stop it until the sample size is big enough to guarantee a statistical significance. My question is, how big have the samples be? or similarly, what's the statistical power at the moment?

Comment: You will do better in my opinion to state what you want to estimate, state the acceptable margin of error in estimating it, and then solve for $N$ that gives you that margin of error.  The margin of error might be $\frac{1}{2}$ the width of the 0.95 confidence limit.  The worst case margin of error is approximately obtained by setting $p=\frac{1}{2}$ and using $1.96 \sqrt(p(1-p)/n_{1} + p(1-p)/n_{2})$ where the two sample sizes are $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$.  You can set the ratio of the sample sizes to a constant $r$ and solve for one of the sample sizes, then the other.

Answer (score 2):

The effect size depends on how rare the Event is. Effect size specified as h parameter refers to cohen's d and is equal $h=2arcsin(\sqrt(p_1))-2arcsin(\sqrt(p_2))$, which means if the proportion in group A is 0.1 and You want to detect statistically significance difference in proportions within groups if the proportion in group B is at least bigger that 5% then You Have to substitute $p_1=0.1,p_2=0.15$ and then $h=0.15..$ and You Have to deliver such value of this parameter into that function.